# Unable to find the Image in pdf - html2pdf?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

My Image tag:

```
<img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg"/>
```

And my html2pdf code:

```
html2pdf(this.$refs.document, {
    margin: 0.2,
    filename: "invoice.pdf",
    pagebreak: {
        after: ".sautDePage"
    },
    image: {
        type: "jpeg",
        quality: 0.98,
    },
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 1,
    },
    jsPDF: {
        unit: "in",
        format: "letter",
        orientation: "portrait",
    },
});
```

Please give me any idea because now my image not display inside pdf. It is visible on page but not in pdf.

Comment: I'm not really into html2pdf hence this is a comment instead of an answer, but maybe CORS is the culprit, according to your image src? There's a solution in https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/105

Comment: I try this, but not works any other suggestions ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the source of the image as a base64 encoded string.

```
  async function convertToDataURL(source) {
    const blob = await fetch(source).then((result) => result.blob());
    const dataUrl = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
    return dataUrl;
  }
```

Set the `src` attribute to the return value of the function above. The parameter `source` is the url to your image.